# warning: braces around scalar initializer

Tags: c, structure

I have this structure

```
    struct Patient
{
    int patientNumber;
    char name[20];
    struct Phone* phone;
};
```

and I'm assigning the data here:

```
int main(void)
{
    struct Patient* pets[MAX_PETS] = { 
        {1024, "Shaggy Yanson", {"CELL","3048005191"} },
        {1032, "Puglsey Yanson", {"CELL","3048005191"} },
        {4040, "Beans Maulin", {"HOME","3649155831"} },
        {1048, "Banjo Codi", {"TBA",{'\0'}} },
        {1056, "Rover Davidov", {"WORK","7934346809"} }
 };
 struct ClinicData data = { pets, MAX_PETS};
```

and I've been receiving these warnings that doesn't let's me move forward.

```
a1m2.c:24:9: warning: braces around scalar initializer
   24 |         {1024, "Shaggy Yanson", {"CELL","3048005191"} },
      |         ^
a1m2.c:24:9: note: (near initialization for ‘pets[0]’)

a1m2.c:25:9: warning: braces around scalar initializer
   25 |         {1032, "Puglsey Yanson", {"CELL","3048005191"} },
      |         ^
a1m2.c:25:9: note: (near initialization for ‘pets[1]’)
```

I've read that is how I'm calling Patient, and I've also tried to change the braces. I don't really know how to fix this :)

Comment: I think you are intending to use `struct Phone phone;` instead of `struct Phone *phone;`, otherwise you will need to explicitly create those phones elsewhere and place it as a pointer, also should be `struct Patient pets[] = {...` rather than `struct Patient *pets[] = {...`.

Comment: Using `""` for empty string instead of `{'\0'}` would look nicer and IMO be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, you would not want to include the asterisk symbol in front of your declaration of your "pets" array.  If you were creating a single new structure and allocating memory for it, the asterisk symbol would be appropriate.  For example.

```
    struct Patient *pats;

    pats = (struct Patient *) malloc(sizeof(struct Patient));

    pats->patientNumber = 3088; /* And so forth */
```

This would set up a single structure, which then could be populated with appropriate data.

In your case, you are actually creating an array of patient structures.  So, in that case, no asterisk is needed.

Using your structure definitions above and completing out definitions for the "Phone" and "ClinicData" structures, I composed the following sample program to utilize your patient structure array along with the phone number structure and the clinic data structure.  I utilized your data for setting up the patient array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_PETS  5

struct Phone
{
    char ptype[5];
    char pnumber[20];
};

struct Patient
{
    int patientNumber;
    char name[20];
    struct Phone phone;
};

struct ClinicData
{
    struct Patient *patients;
    int    elements;
};

int main()
{
    struct Patient pets[MAX_PETS] =                     /* Removed the "*" as "pets" by itself is in effect a pointer */
    {
        {1024, "Shaggy Yanson", {"CELL","3048005191"} },
        {1032, "Puglsey Yanson", {"CELL","3048005191"} },
        {4040, "Beans Maulin", {"HOME","3649155831"} },
        {1048, "Banjo Codi", {"TBA",{'\0'}} },
        {1056, "Rover Davidov", {"WORK","7934346809"} }
    };

    struct ClinicData data = { pets, MAX_PETS};

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_PETS; i++)
    {
        printf("Here is a patient #%d: %s\n", i, data.patients[i].name);  /* Dealing with structure array elements so "." is being used in lieu of "->" */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Hopefully, this sheds light on the declaration of a structure array and gives you some food for thought.

Regards.